# Update meta field value before custom post load then display post with updated meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, api

## What I'm trying to do

I'm currently working on a way to update the price of a product when a user go on the product page.
I'm using an API to get the accurate price.

## The problem

The function properly update the meta field `sellers` on back end, but the value of the meta field won't show on front, even after refresh. I have to update the post manually in the back end for the meta field `sellers` to show on front when refreshing the page.

## What I managed to do so far

I managed to handle the API request, then parsed the response. I also managed to fire the API request and modify the price if necessary in the meta field of my product page with an add_action hook. I'm currently using `send_headers` hook, which is probably not the one to go with but at least it's kinda working :p

## The code

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'fetch_seller_price' );

function fetch_seller_price(){
    
    //check if is front
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        
        //Check if is custom post type
        if ('bons-plans' == get_post_type( $post_id )) {
            
            //Get ASIN code from custom meta field
            $asin_code = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'asin_code', true );

            //check if product code is correct
            if (strlen( $asin_code ) == 10) {
                
                $sellers = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sellers', true);

                foreach ($sellers as $item => $value) {
                    
                    //Check if seller is Amazon
                    if ($value["seller"] == "Amazon") {
                        
                        //get price from api function
                        $item_price = amazon_price_request( $asin_code );
                        //If new price != old price, update sellers array with new product price value 
                        if ($value["product-price"] != $item_price) {
                            $sellers[$item]["product-price"] = $item_price;
                            
                        }
                    }
                
                update_post_meta( $post_id, "sellers", $sellers );
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

note: `sellers` meta field is an nested array whitch contains multiple `seller` arrays of that form:

```
["item-2"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["seller"]=>
    string(6) "Amazon"
    ["product-link"]=>
    string(23) "https://amzn.to/3E90AFS"
    ["product-price"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    }
```

I tried to `var_dump()` the `sellers` array after loading the page on front, and also tried with `item_price` variable. Both return the right number, but the end result appear as it it were empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

I'm kinda new to PHP and I'm well aware my code is kind of trashy, any idea on how to make it proper is also accepted :p

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins (e.g. W3 Total Cache) installed? If yes, try to temporarily disable them to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried but nothing changed. The area where the variable is supposed to be is in this form :

`<div class="jet-button__state jet-button__state-normal">
          <span class="jet-button__label">23.61 €</span>
</div>`

But for the part not returning any value, it's missing the `span` and appear like this :
`<div class="jet-button__state jet-button__state-normal"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem where simply the way I parsed the json response, variable was `float` formated, and the expected format was a `string` :p